Bootstrap failed to fatch
I have just setup openshift UPI baremetal environment .
Machine-1: base OS centos stream9 : services install HAproxy,nfs , apache
1 bootstrap redhat coreos
3 master
3 worker
Once my bootstrap install and ready to run I encounter errors
ay 28 15:16:43 bootstrap.openshift.ocp4.lab bootkube.sh[17963]: [#326] failed to fetch discovery: Get "https://localhost:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused May 28 15:16:43 bootstrap.openshift.ocp4.lab cluster-bootstrap[17987]: [#327] failed to fetch discovery: Get "https://localhost:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused 
I dont know what cause this issue ? any idea
Regards
I could not find the issue to resolve :(
